# Different syntax highlighting on mvim/vim when using console

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax-highlighting, macvim

Using MVIM on GUI I get the syntax on the right. Using `mvim -v\` or `vim` on the console, I get no syntax at all, but after a `:syntax on` if becomes the image on the left, which is still not the coloring I'm used to. What's going on?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Graphical vim can use other configuration file (`~/.gvimrc` vs `~/.vimrc`), and due to that `vim` after star differs from `mvim`. Regarding the differences in colours, consoles aren't able to use full RGB which are available for graphical interfaces, so your colour scheme is somehow 'approximated'.

Answer (score 0):

The color scheme is defined by `:colorscheme [scheme]`. If you run without the argument, you can check which is in use by running it without the argument.

Two files are normally used to customize vim. You should check then to see where `colorscheme` is being set.

- General vim (GUI and CLI) customization goes on `.vimrc`.
- GUI-only customization goes on `.gvimrc`.

Scripts can also be overwriting the options in these files. You could use `:scriptnames` to check which ones are currently in use, to help you find what's going on.